# How to add custom places to the Google maps API in the search box in ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can we add custom-places-to-the-Google-maps-API-in-the-search-box in Google map
i want to show the search hospitals, clinics, related shops, pharmacies, health and fitness centers and see how far are they from the km. All these places locations are going to be shown in my Google map along with Marker.

Comment: What do you mean by add custom places? Are those places that don't show up on Google maps?

Comment: You could use Places API https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search